# Specific Binary XML file line #133 exception while inflating fragment class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I've already seen similar errors, but none of them helps me. I have activity in which I can put pictures from gallery on button clicked. So, when I choose picture and try to get back to activity, I get this error.

```
    11-14 15:00:26.884: W/dalvikvm(19944): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught          exception (group=0x40c4a1f8)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{rs.telegraf.io/rs.telegraf.io.MainActivitySendNews}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class fragment
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class fragment
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at rs.telegraf.io.MainActivitySendNews.onCreate(MainActivitySendNews.java:145)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    ... 11 more
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment rs.telegraf.io.Fragment did not create a view.
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:303)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    11-14 15:00:26.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    ... 24 more
```

I guess maybe I should inflate my fragmet earlier or something like this. And one more interesting fact, it happens only sometimes, and sometimess I add picture and get back to MainActivitySendNews activity normally.This is my xml file in which exception happens and my MainActivitySendNews class in which I make this fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#EEEEEE" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/naslov_opis"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/opis" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/kategorija_opis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/naslov_opis"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/izbor_kat_naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dodaj_kategorija" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/prva_linija_naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/izbor_kat_naslov"
                android:background="#D5D5D5" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/druga_linija_naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/izbor_kat_naslov"
                android:background="#D5D5D5" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/izbor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/kategorija_opis"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/srednja"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#EEEEEE" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_odabir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/izbor"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dodaj"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dodaj" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/prva_linija"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dodaj"
                android:background="#D5D5D5" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/duga_linija"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dodaj"
                android:background="#D5D5D5" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <rs.telegraf.io.ExpandableHeightGridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/relative_odabir"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
        </rs.telegraf.io.ExpandableHeightGridView>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="rs.telegraf.io.Fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/gridview"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            class="rs.telegraf.io.Fragment" >
        </fragment>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/odustani"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/srednja"
            android:layout_below="@id/fragment"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/razma_dugmici"
            android:background="@drawable/odustani_selector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/posalji"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/srednja"
            android:layout_below="@id/fragment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/razma_dugmici"
            android:background="@drawable/posalji_selector" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is OnCreate method of MainActivitySendNews:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_news_main);
    pictureAlertWithContent.add(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.item_click_send_new_camera));
    pictureAlertWithContent.add(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.item_click_send_new_galery));
    pictureAlertWithContent.add(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.item_click_send_new_delete));

    pictureAlertEmpty.add(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.item_click_send_new_camera));
    pictureAlertEmpty.add(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.item_click_send_new_galery));
    pictureAlertEmpty.add(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.item_click_send_new_delete));

    ScrollView src = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    src.setClickable(false);

    cansel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.odustani);

    cansel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
    // kamera=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.kamera);
    // galerija=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.galerija);
    posalji = (Button) findViewById(R.id.posalji);
    posalji.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // cansel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // intent_for_galery = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
    imageItems = getData();

    pictures.put("0", "empty");
    pictures.put("1", "empty");
    pictures.put("2", "empty");
    pictures.put("3", "empty");
    pictures.put("4", "empty");
    pictures.put("5", "empty");
    gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid,
            imageItems);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    gridView.setExpanded(true);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            if ((pictures.get(String.valueOf(position)).equals("empty"))) {
                dialog_choise = onCreateDialogSingleChoice(position);

                dialog_choise.show();
            } else {
                dialog_choise = onCreateDialogSingleChoiceWithContent(position);

                dialog_choise.show();

            }
        }
    });
    // lista za izbor vrste oglasa

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.izbor);
    fragmenti = new ArrayList<rs.telegraf.io.Fragment>();
    adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_za_spinner);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivitySendNews.this);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    new load().execute("");

    int i = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (i == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        margine(i);
    posalji.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean for_send = true;

            if (number_of_pictures != 6) {
                userDetJson = new JSONObject();
                userDetJsonArray = new JSONArray();
                List<EditText> editboxesEditTexts = fragmenti.get(
                        position_spiner).getEditboxes();
                List<String> parameters = fragmenti.get(position_spiner)
                        .getData().getParametri();
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < editboxesEditTexts.size(); i++) {

                        String tmp = String.valueOf(parameters.get(i)
                                .charAt(0));

                        if (tmp.equals("*"))

                        {
                            if ((editboxesEditTexts.get(i).getText()
                                    .toString()).equals("")) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        getString(R.string.please)
                                                + " "
                                                + editboxesEditTexts.get(i)
                                                        .getHint(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                for_send = false;
                                break;
                            }

                            else {

                                userDetJson.put(parameters.get(i),
                                        editboxesEditTexts.get(i).getText());
                            }
                        } else {

                            userDetJson.put(parameters.get(i),
                                    editboxesEditTexts.get(i).getText());

                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            } else {

                for_send = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.error_number_picture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            if (!pick_category) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Morate izabrati kategoriju", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            if (for_send && pick_category) {
                new SendData().execute();
                finish();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: When asking a question, try to minimize the code to the relevant parts and try to ask a clear question. This encourages people to invest the time to help you and it helps users that find this question in the future

Comment: do you instantiate you fragment anywhere? the error tells you that fragment view was never created

Comment: Yes, I instantiated my fragment, but I think I found mistake. In my sendNews activity, I just replaced my xml with new fragments when necessary, and now, in onCreate method I firstly dynamically added fragment to my xml, and later just changed that fragment with new ones. And now exception doesn't occur.

There's only one strange thing. On Samsung tablet, when I get back from gallery(when adding pictures), half of the SendNews activity gets black and stays like that until I touch the screen. Then, screen becomes normal(white, as it should be). Can it be also connected with these fragments?